# Why won't Mathematica obtain eigenvectors for this symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

The matrix is a real symmetric 4x4:

```
({{0, Sin[x + y], Sin[z + y], Sin[x + z]},
  {Sin[x + y], 0, Sin[x - z], Sin[z - y]},
  {Sin[z + y], Sin[x - z], 0, Sin[y - x]},
  {Sin[x + z], Sin[z - y], Sin[y - x], 0}})
```

Mathematica can find the eigenvalues fine, and they are degenerate for x, y, and/or z equal to zero.

No eigenvectors can be found:
Eigenvectors::eivec0: Unable to find all eigenvectors.
And it seems to me that Mathematica should be able to handle the degeneracy, but I would be interested to know why it is encountering trouble.

Is there some obvious property about this matrix that I am not accounting for (such as restricting values of x, y, z for the trigonometric functions) or is there something I can do inside of Mathematica to specify some starting point for an eigenvalue?

Comment: Setting your matrix equal to `mat`, `Eigenvectors[mat]` returns a large output and `Eigenvectors[mat,1]` returns what is presumably an eigenvector.  (This is in v10.)  Can you explain what you are doing to generate the error?

Comment: ...and v9 does appear to struggle with `Eigenvectors[mat,1]`, let along finding all Eigenvectors, which I did not attempt yet.

Comment: I am using v9, there's not much I can do about that. All I did was Eigenvectors[mat], and it returns the error message and four zero eigenvectors.

I realize the closed form output will be large, but ultimately I will pick out pieces of the expressions for other things (e.g. the Root pieces proving whether values of x, y, z can produce imaginary eigenvectors).

Any idea why v9 struggles?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your systerm is timing out.

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"

```
mat = ({{0, Sin[x + y], Sin[z + y], Sin[x + z]}, {Sin[x + y], 0, Sin[x - z], 
     Sin[z - y]}, {Sin[z + y], Sin[x - z], 0, Sin[y - x]}, {Sin[x + z], 
     Sin[z - y], Sin[y - x], 0}});

eval = Eigenvalues[mat] // Simplify;

Length[eval]
```

> 4

```
eval /. {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0}

```
Timing[evec = Eigenvectors[mat] // Simplify;]
```

> {107.624447, Null}

```
Length[evec]
```

> 4

The symbolic eigenvectors are very complicated. For example, just the first eigenvector (simplified) is

```
evec[[1]]
```

> {-((3 Sin[x - 3 y] - 3 Sin[3 x - y] - 5 Sin[x + y] + Sin[3 (x + y)] + 
>         Sin[3 x + y - 2 z] + Sin[x + 3 y - 2 z] + 
>         4 Sin[x + 
>            y] [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>             Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>             2 Cos[4 z] - 
>             2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2)) + 
>         2 Sqrt[2] Cos[
>           x - y - 2 z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>             Cos[2 y] Cos[
>               2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] +
>                 Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>                2 Cos[4 z] - 
>                2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) - 
>         2 Sqrt[2] Cos[
>           x - y + 2 z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>             Cos[2 y] Cos[
>               2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] +
>                 Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>                2 Cos[4 z] - 
>                2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) + 
>         Sin[3 x + y + 2 z] + Sin[x + 3 y + 2 z])/(Sin[2 x + y - 3 z] - 
>         5 Sin[y - z] + Sin[3 (y - z)] + Sin[2 x + 3 y - z] + 
>         4 Sin[y - 
>            z] [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>             Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>             2 Cos[4 z] - 
>             2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2)) - 
>         2 Sqrt[2] Cos[
>           2 x - y - 
>            z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>             Cos[2 y] Cos[
>               2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] +
>                 Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>                2 Cos[4 z] - 
>                2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) + 
>         2 Sqrt[2] Cos[
>           2 x + y + 
>            z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>             Cos[2 y] Cos[
>               2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] +
>                 Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>                2 Cos[4 z] - 
>                2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) - 
>         Sin[2 x - 3 y + z] - 3 Sin[3 y + z] - Sin[2 x - y + 3 z] + 
>         3 Sin[y + 3 z])), (8 Cos[x] Cos[y]^2 Sin[x] - 
>       8 Cos[x] Cos[z]^2 Sin[x] - 8 Cos[x]^2 Cos[y] Sin[y] + 
>       8 Cos[y] Cos[z]^2 Sin[y] + 8 Cos[y] Sin[x]^2 Sin[y] - 
>       8 Cos[x] Sin[x] Sin[y]^2 - 8 Cos[x]^2 Cos[z] Sin[z] + 
>       8 Cos[y]^2 Cos[z] Sin[z] + 8 Cos[z] Sin[x]^2 Sin[z] - 
>       8 Cos[z] Sin[y]^2 Sin[z] + 8 Cos[x] Sin[x] Sin[z]^2 - 
>       8 Cos[y] Sin[y] Sin[z]^2 - 
>       2 Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x] Sin[
>         2 y] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>           Cos[2 y] Cos[
>             2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>              Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>              2 Cos[4 z] - 
>              2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) + 
>       2 Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x] Sin[
>         2 z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>           Cos[2 y] Cos[
>             2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>              Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>              2 Cos[4 z] - 
>              2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) + 
>       2 Sqrt[2] Sin[2 y] Sin[
>         2 z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>           Cos[2 y] Cos[
>             2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>              Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>              2 Cos[4 z] - 
>              2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) + 
>       2 Sqrt[2] [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>           Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>           2 Cos[4 z] - 
>           2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2)) [Sqrt](3 - 
>           Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>           Cos[2 y] Cos[
>             2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>              Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>              2 Cos[4 z] - 
>              2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))))/(Sin[
>        2 x + y - 3 z] - 5 Sin[y - z] + Sin[3 (y - z)] + Sin[2 x + 3 y - z] + 
>       4 Sin[y - 
>          z] [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>           Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>           2 Cos[4 z] - 
>           2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2)) - 
>       2 Sqrt[2] Cos[
>         2 x - y - 
>          z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>           Cos[2 y] Cos[
>             2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>              Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>              2 Cos[4 z] - 
>              2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) + 
>       2 Sqrt[2] Cos[
>         2 x + y + 
>          z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>           Cos[2 y] Cos[
>             2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>              Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>              2 Cos[4 z] - 
>              2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) - 
>       Sin[2 x - 3 y + z] - 3 Sin[3 y + z] - Sin[2 x - y + 3 z] + 
>       3 Sin[y + 3 z]), -((Sin[x - 2 y - 3 z] + Sin[x + 2 y - 3 z] - 
>         5 Sin[x - z] + Sin[3 (x - z)] + Sin[3 x - 2 y - z] + 
>         Sin[3 x + 2 y - z] + 
>         4 Sin[x - 
>            z] [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>             Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>             2 Cos[4 z] - 
>             2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2)) + 
>         2 Sqrt[2] Cos[
>           x - 2 y + 
>            z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>             Cos[2 y] Cos[
>               2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] +
>                 Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>                2 Cos[4 z] - 
>                2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) - 
>         2 Sqrt[2] Cos[
>           x + 2 y + 
>            z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>             Cos[2 y] Cos[
>               2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] +
>                 Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>                2 Cos[4 z] - 
>                2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) - 
>         3 Sin[3 x + z] + 3 Sin[x + 3 z])/(Sin[2 x + y - 3 z] - 5 Sin[y - z] + 
>         Sin[3 (y - z)] + Sin[2 x + 3 y - z] + 
>         4 Sin[y - 
>            z] [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + 
>             Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>             2 Cos[4 z] - 
>             2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2)) - 
>         2 Sqrt[2] Cos[
>           2 x - y - 
>            z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>             Cos[2 y] Cos[
>               2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] +
>                 Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>                2 Cos[4 z] - 
>                2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) + 
>         2 Sqrt[2] Cos[
>           2 x + y + 
>            z] [Sqrt](3 - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] - Cos[2 x] Cos[2 z] - 
>             Cos[2 y] Cos[
>               2 z] - [Sqrt](3 - 2 Cos[4 x] - 2 Cos[4 y] - 2 Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] +
>                 Cos[2 y]^2 Cos[2 z]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2 (Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 z])^2 - 
>                2 Cos[4 z] - 
>                2 Cos[2 x] (Cos[2 z] Sin[2 y]^2 + Cos[2 y] Sin[2 z]^2))) - 
>         Sin[2 x - 3 y + z] - 3 Sin[3 y + z] - Sin[2 x - y + 3 z] + 
>         3 Sin[y + 3 z])), 1}